# Android Application Crashed After Obfuscation Using Proguard

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, proguard, obfuscation, cordova-plugin-proguard

I used Proguard to obfuscate my android source and try to sign my app and succeed. No error found when I sign the app. But, after I installed my app to my device, the application got force closed when I try to open the app. Below is the error that I got:

```
W/dalvikvm( 1351): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 159: Landroid/content/C
ontext;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm( 1351): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
I/dalvikvm( 1351): Could not find method org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttp
Client.getCookieStore, referenced from method com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClien
t.getCookieStore
W/dalvikvm( 1351): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 24031: Lorg/apache/http
/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient;.getCookieStore ()Lorg/apache/a/a/a;
D/dalvikvm( 1351): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
I/dalvikvm( 1351): Could not find method org.apache.http.HttpRequest.addHeader,
referenced from method com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.addExtraHeaders
W/dalvikvm( 1351): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 23989: Lorg/apache/ht
tp/HttpRequest;.addHeader (Lorg/apache/a/a;)V
D/dalvikvm( 1351): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0019
D/dalvikvm( 1351): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 11% free 3042K/3384K, paused 5ms+2m
s, total 84ms
I/dalvikvm( 1351): Could not find method org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttp
Client.setCookieStore, referenced from method com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientM
anager.<init>
W/dalvikvm( 1351): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 24033: Lorg/apache/http
/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient;.setCookieStore (Lorg/apache/a/a/a;)V
D/dalvikvm( 1351): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099
D/AndroidRuntime( 1351): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1351): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb
1a82ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351): Process: com.ACCTouch, PID: 1351
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.clien
t.DefaultHttpClient.setCookieStore
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientManager.<ini
t>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientManager.crea
teInstance(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.createIns
tance(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Unknow
n Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL.<init>(Unknow
n Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL.createInstanc
e(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.ACCTouch.ACCTouch.onCreate(Unknown Source
)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.j
ava:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCre
ate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivi
ty(ActivityThread.java:2245)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(Activit
yThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
tivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
15)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1351):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/ActivityManager(  377):   Force finishing activity com.ACCTouch/.ACCTouch
W/InputMethodManagerService(  377): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain
of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b20e15d8 attribute=n
ull, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b1fab568
W/ActivityManager(  377): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b1fd3570 u0
com.ACCTouch/.ACCTouch t5 f}
W/ActivityManager(  377): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b1fd3570 u
0 com.ACCTouch/.ACCTouch t5 f}
```

And below is my proguard config:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# These options let obfuscated applications or libraries produce stack traces that can still be deciphered later on
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile.LineNumberTable
-keepattributes InnerClasses

# Enable proguard with Cordova
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** {
    *;
}
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin

-keep class com.worklight.androidgap.push.** {
    *;
}
-keep class com.worklight.wlclient.push.** {
    *;
}
-keep class com.worklight.common.security.AppAuthenticityToken {
    *;
}

# Enable proguard with Google Libs
-keep class com.google.** {
    *;
}
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**

# These classes contain references to external jars which are not included in the default MobileFirst project

-dontwarn com.worklight.common.internal.WLTrusteerInternal*
-dontwarn com.worklight.jsonstore.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.**
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.push.GCMIntentService
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService

-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.WLBroadcastReceiver
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.common.*
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush

-dontwarn net.sqlchiper.**
-dontwarn net.sqlchiper.database.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

-keep class org.apache.http.** {
    *;
}

-keep class com.worklight.** {
    *;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** {
    *;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.database.** {
    *;
}

-keep class org.apache.commons.codec.** {
    *;
}

-keep class **.R
```

I've tried to add this code: `-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }` to my proguard config, but now I got this error that said I have duplicate class definitions when I try to sign the app.

```
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid] Note: there were 27 duplicate class definitions.
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.obfuscate.MemberObfuscator.newMemberName(MemberObfuscator.java:198)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.obfuscate.MemberNameCollector.visitAnyMember(MemberNameCollector.java:74)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMember(SimplifiedVisitor.java:79)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.MemberAccessFilter.visitProgramMethod(MemberAccessFilter.java:90)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMemberVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMemberVisitor.java:48)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.hierarchyAccept(ProgramClass.java:359)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.LibraryClass.hierarchyAccept(LibraryClass.java:371)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.hierarchyAccept(ProgramClass.java:416)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.ClassHierarchyTraveler.visitProgramClass(ClassHierarchyTraveler.java:75)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.MultiClassVisitor.visitProgramClass(MultiClassVisitor.java:85)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.obfuscate.Obfuscator.execute(Obfuscator.java:217)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.ProGuard.obfuscate(ProGuard.java:333)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:135)
[2016-01-08 11:39:54 - ACCTouchACCTouchAndroid]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

FYI: I am currently working this on Mobile First ver. 7.1.

> Update: Now I am able to solve it by adding this code to my proguard config: `-keep class org.apache.http.client.** { *; }`, but now my app still crashed inside and i got this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-3
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522): Process: com.ACCTouch, PID: 2522
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.HttpReques
t.getFirstHeader
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522):        at com.worklight.wlclient.AsynchronousRequestSen
der.addGlobalHeadersToRequest(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522):        at com.worklight.wlclient.AsynchronousRequestSen
der.sendWLHybridRequestAsync(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522):        at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRSe
nder.sendRequest(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522):        at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPl
ugin$1.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWo
rker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worke
r.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2522):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Which app type did you use.... Native android, hybrid app with android environment or Cordova app with android platform?

Comment: I am using hybrid app with android environment. I am able to solve it just now by adding this code: '-keep class org.apache.http.client.** { *; }' to my proguard config, but now I got error: 'NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.HttpRequest.getFirstHandler' and my app force closed

Comment: you can modify -keep class org.apache.http.client.** { \*; } to -keep class org.apache.** { *; }

Comment: You could try to keep class org.apache.* like Rajen suggested. If it still gives you issues, provide the project.

Comment: I have tried the suggestion that Rajen suggested but now I got error: 'there were 27 duplicate class definitions.' when signing the apk.

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE:** Thank you all for your suggestion. I able to solve it just now by adding these codes below to my proguard config:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.client.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.cookie.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.message.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.util.** { *; }
```

I still don't know though why I can't just add `-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }` to my proguard config.

Comment: You need to add -keep class org.apache.http.** { *; } because Cordova runs on webview.